# google map lightbox

Tags: jquery, google-maps, lightbox

I have an image of a map to my office that I would like to use on my website, but I want there to be the option for the user to click on the image to pull up the google maps location in a lightbox....

I have looked through the questions here to find the answer, but cannot seem to find it!

Essentially, I have:

```
<a href="http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?q=????????&hl=en&sll=???????,-???????1&sspn=??.??????,??.5??????&z=??" target="_blank"><img src="css/images/map.gif" width="655" height="320" /></a>
```

Map.gif is an animated gif. The only javascript I currently have on the page is

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.4.3.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){  // $(document).ready shorthand
$('#map').hide().fadeIn(2000);
});
</script>
```

which fades the image into the screen. Any ideas!!

Thanks
JD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my way of handeling such an event

1. insert `<div id='lightbox' class='white_content'></div>` and `<div id='fade' class='class='black_overlay'></div>` into your html file.

2.Your CSS for the lightbox:

```
.white_content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 25%;
    width: 650px;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 16px;
    border: 16px solid white;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: white;
    z-index:1002;
    overflow: auto;
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px black;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px black;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px black;
}
   .black_overlay{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
        top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    z-index:1001;
    -moz-opacity: 0.5;
    opacity:.50;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

1. And finaly you need a javascript:

   `function showLightBox() { 
           document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';
           document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block';
     }`

When you want to hide the lightbox, you make a custom function to call, that sets `document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';` and `document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none';`

To get the google map inside your lightbox, use this line of code inside your javascript:

```
document.getElementById('light').innerHTML = " content to show here ";
```

to push content to your lightbox. Normaly you use Ajax to get content to a lightbox

If you don't know how to embed google maps, you can finde the documentation here:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/